# Using gsub to extract the capital letters in a string

Tags: r

I have a string which can be seen below where I wish to extract the country code, although it gets a bit fiddly with the special characters in there too. I've tried to extract it by using a gsub of everything up until the capital letters, and everything after but this was unsuccesful.

```
mystring
[1] "        data-country=\"GER\">"
```

I've tried using (below) but this was unsuccessful as it just seemed to split the GER rather than keep it

```
gsub('(.+)[A-Z](.+)', '\\1', mystring)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `[^A-Z]` to remove everything what is not a capital letter.

```
gsub("[^A-Z]", "", mystring)
#[1] "GER"
```

Answer (score 2):

These all assume that what is wanted is to extract the portion within double quotes and that there is one pair of double quotes.

**1)** Use `scan` and take second component:

```
scan(text = string, what = "", sep = '"', quiet = TRUE)[2]
## [1] "GER"
```

**2)** `sub` matching any characters, a double quote, any characters (capturing that), a double quote and any characters returning the captured part.

```
sub('.*"(.*)".*', "\\1", string)
## [1] "GER"
```

**3)** `strsplit` would also work

```
unlist(strsplit(string, '"'))[2]
## [1] "GER"
```

**4)** We can use `trimws` twice first trimming the non-double-quotes on the ends and then trimming the double quotes:

```
trimws(trimws(string,,'[^"]'),,'"')
## [1] "GER"
```

**5)** `read.table` approach is similar to `scan`:

```
read.table(text = string, sep = '"')[[2]]
## [1] "GER"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub` with a capture group in between two quotation marks:

```r
gsub("^.*\"(.*)\".*$", "\\1", mystring)
#> [1] "GER"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `[A-Z]` or `[[:upper:]]` to capture upper case letters.

```
gsub(".+?([[:upper:]]{1,}).*$", "\\1", mystring)
[1] "GER"

#or

library(stringr)

str_extract(mystring, "[A-Z]{1,}")
[1] "GER"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(mystring, "[A-Z]+")

[1] "GER"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a data frame like this, you could make this:

```
letras <- data.frame(
  data=c("data-country=\"GER\">","data-country=\"ITA\">","data-country=\"SPN\">",
         "data-country=\"BRA\">"))
letras$mayusculas <- gsub(".*?([A-Z]+).*", "\\1", letras$data)
letras

#     data               mayusculas
#  data-country="GER">        GER
#  data-country="ITA">        ITA
#  data-country="SPN">        SPN
#  data-country="BRA">        BRA
```